# tkinter apply method not found in module

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, optionmenu

Below you can see the code I have for a method in my GUI Class. I have been trying to create an option menu from a list however I am getting an error. It says that tkinter has no module 'apply'. In all the examples I can find people use Tkinter instead of tkinter, so has there been a change in the apply method from python 2.x to 3.x?

I have tried writing all of the following:
tk.apply, tk.Apply, apply. But nothing seems to work.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI:
     def UploadHomeworkScreen(self):
         self.masternew = tk.Tk()
         self.framenew = tk.Frame(self.masternew)
         self.HomeworkFileEntry = tk.Entry(self.framenew)
         self.ClassVariable = tk.StringVar(self.masternew)
         self.ClassVariable.set(Client.ListOfClasses[0])
         self.ClassChoice = tk.apply(tk.OptionMenu, (self.framenew, self.ClassVariable) + tuple(Client.ListOfClasses))
         self.SubmitButton = tk.Button(self.framenew, text = "Submit", command = self.SubmitHomework)
         self.HomeworkFileEntry.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)
         self.ClassChoice.pack()
         self.SubmitButton.pack()
         self.framenew.pack()
         self.masternew.mainloop()
```

I am open to creating the option menu another way if it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `import tkinter`?

Comment: please show the exact error. And why do you think that tkinter has something named `apply`? What do you think it does?

Comment: the last paragraph(s) of [effbot's documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm#ft) shows an `apply` function. This doesn't seem to work as it did then.

Comment: In my own use of apply, I get a NameError, which says apply is not defined

Comment: Apparently `apply` was [removed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html?highlight=apply#2to3fixer-apply) in python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Note: apply() doesn't exist in Python 3. Any guide that uses it(notably, the tkinterbook on effbot.org) is horribly out of date.

Per tkinter's definition for `class OptionMenu(Menubutton)`:

The OptionMenu is initialized as such:

```
    def __init__(self, master, variable, value, *values, **kwargs):
            """Construct an optionmenu widget with the parent MASTER, with
            the resource textvariable set to VARIABLE, the initially selected
            value VALUE, the other menu values VALUES and an additional
            keyword argument command."""
```

Taking that into account, your code line:

```
     self.ClassChoice = tk.apply(tk.OptionMenu, (self.framenew, self.ClassVariable) + tuple(Client.ListOfClasses))
```

Should be changed to:

```
     self.ClassChoice = tk.OptionMenu(self.framenew, self.ClassVariable, *Client.ListOfClasses)
```

Note the asterisk before `Client.ListOfClasses`. This is to pass in the menu VALUES needed by the OptionMenu as a list, per https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists.

Answer (score 0):

The `apply` function has been removed in Python 3.[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html?highlight=apply#2to3fixer-apply) It was not a `tkinter` specific function. To fix this, use the first parameter of the `apply` function as the function name, like so:

Your code:

```
self.ClassChoice = tk.apply(tk.OptionMenu, (self.framenew, self.ClassVariable) + tuple(Client.ListOfClasses))
```

New:

```
self.ClassChoice = tk.OptionMenu((self.framenew, self.ClassVariable) + tuple(Client.ListOfClasses))
```

Or as the documentation for `2to3` says, "`apply(function, *args, **kwargs)` is converted to `function(*args, **kwargs)`."